# Issue in calling shell script from qt .pro file on Mac Machine

Tags: macos, qt, shell

We are facing very strange issue in running `Shell Script` file from **'QT'** .pro file on Mac system(For our cross platform Qt project).

Same .pro file is working fine on Ubuntu machine without any issues.

We have following command for running script file which compiles .ts([Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)) files into .js(javascript) files.

```
# TypeScript Compilation
{
  PRE_BUILD_FILE = "$${PWD}/external/TSbuild/compileTS.sh"
  DUMMY_DEPS = .
  PreBuildEvent.input = DUMMY_DEPS
  PreBuildEvent.output = DUMMY.txt
  PreBuildEvent.commands = $$PRE_BUILD_FILE
  PreBuildEvent.name = running Pre-Build steps...
  # "target_predeps" tells qmake that the output of this needs to exist before we can do     the rest of our compilation.
  PreBuildEvent.CONFIG += no_link no_clean target_predeps
  QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += PreBuildEvent
}
```

our script file looks like this

```
BASEDIR=$(dirname "$0")
echo "===============================================";
echo "Script Directory is: " $BASEDIR;
echo "===============================================";
tsc -p "$BASEDIR/tsconfig.json";
cd $BASEDIR/../../web/js/;
rm -r autogen_*.js;
rename 's/^/autogen_/' *.js;
exit 0;
```

We are getting following error while building code

```
'tsc' command not found.

'rename' command not found.
```

**Note 1:** Same script is running fine, if we run it from terminal using command in that directory  or from other directory giving path.

```
$sh compileTS.sh
```

**Note 2:** If we change script file in following way.

```
BASEDIR=$(dirname "$0")
echo "===============================================";
echo "Script Directory is: " $BASEDIR;
echo "===============================================";
/usr/local/bin/tsc -p "$BASEDIR/tsconfig.json";
cd $BASEDIR/../../web/js/;
rm -r autogen_*.js;
/usr/local/bin/rename 's/^/autogen_/' *.js;
exit 0;
```

We are getting error message.

```
env: node: No such file or directory
```

Meaning script file **was** not able to find path of 'tsc'. Now file is not finding path of 'node'. means need to give complete path of command.

**Note 3:** 
Same .pro file code is building without any issues on Linux. Linux we faced small issues, due to calling of script file.

```
PreBuildEvent.commands = .$$PRE_BUILD_FILE
```

Removed '.' to make it work.

```
PreBuildEvent.commands = $$PRE_BUILD_FILE
```

as ‘.’ causes running script in same directory as calling process.

**Note 4:** We also had try with calling script file in different way, nothing helped

```
PreBuildEvent.commands = .$$PRE_BUILD_FILE


PreBuildEvent.commands = sh $$PRE_BUILD_FILE
```

**Note 5:** Even updating 'PATH' variable, updating 'bash_profile' didn't helped. [Setting up environment variable](https://medium.com/@himanshuagarwal1395/setting-up-environment-variables-in-macos-sierra-f5978369b255)

Please guild us resolving this issue, may be some small mistake due to limited knowledge in Shell script and way of calling Shell script in mac system.